# how to set temporary backup location for vps in virtulizor?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization

i,m new to virtulizor and i have setup a ftp backup server.
after a while i realized that you need to have enough empty space on your hard drives for virtulizor to be able to create a temporary backup file before transferring it to the ftp server.
if not the virtulizor will genereate an error saying it cannot create a temporary file.
since i have multiple hard drives on my server and for some reason virtulizor decided to choose my ssd drive to use as temporary location i cannot backup my larger VPSs that are located on my HDD drives.
is there any way to determine this location or at least change the hard drive for it?
i,m running virtulizor 2.9.7 on cent OS 7.5 and kvm virtualization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when adding a storage device for a VPS you can set it as primary storage which will cause virtulizor to use it as temporary backup location (this is not mentioned in their documents or descriptions). so i just went to my HDD storage settings and selected primary storage option.